# Pagination doesn't load data in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

Im trying make a pagination, but nothing happens with my table, no errors, just doesn't load the data

Pagination.ts:

```
export interface PageQuery {
  pageNumber: number;
  pageSize: number;
}

export interface QueryBuilder {
  pageQuery: PageQuery;
  aditionalQuery: Map<string, string>;
  buildQueryMap(): Map<string, string>;
  buildQueryString(): string;
  buildPageQueryMap(): Map<string, string>;
}

export class PageRequest implements QueryBuilder {
  constructor(
    public _pageQuery: PageQuery,
    public _aditionalQuery: Map<string, string>
  ) {}
  public pageQuery!: PageQuery;
  public aditionalQuery!: Map<string, string>;

  buildQueryMap(): Map<string, string> {
    let buildQueryMap = new Map<string, string>([...this.buildPageQueryMap()]);
    if (this.aditionalQuery) {
      buildQueryMap = new Map<string, string>([
        ...buildQueryMap,
        ...this.aditionalQuery,
      ]);
    }

    return buildQueryMap;
  }
  buildQueryString(): string {
    return Array.from(this.buildQueryMap())
      .map((itemArray) => `${itemArray[0]}=${itemArray[1]}`)
      .join('&');
  }
  buildPageQueryMap(): Map<string, string> {
    let buildPageQueryMap = new Map<string, string>();

    buildPageQueryMap.set(
      'page',
      `${this.pageQuery?.pageNumber ? this.pageQuery.pageNumber + 1 : 0}`
    );
    buildPageQueryMap.set(
      'size',
      `${this.pageQuery?.pageSize ? this.pageQuery.pageSize : 5}`
    );

    return buildPageQueryMap;
  }
}

export class Page<T> {
  constructor(public content: T[], public totalElements: number) {}

  static fromResponse<T>(response: any) {
    return new Page<T>(
      response.body,
      parseInt(response.headers.get('X-total-Count'))
    );
  }
}
```

service.ts:

```
export class VeiculoService {
  private readonly API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/veiculos';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  list() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Veiculos[]>(this.API);
  }

  listPage(queryBuilder: QueryBuilder): Observable<Page<Veiculos>> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Veiculos[]>(`${this.API}?${queryBuilder.buildQueryString()}`, {
        observe: 'response',
      })
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => <Page<Veiculos>>Page.fromResponse(response))
      );
  }
```

component.ts:

```
  export class VeiculoComponent implements OnInit {
  veiculos: Veiculos[] = [];
  page: Page<Veiculos> = new Page([], 0);
  pages = new MatTableDataSource<Page<Veiculos>>();
  pageEvent!: PageEvent;
  displayedColumns = ['placaOriginal', 'placaFria', 'modelo', 'marca', 'ano'];

  addVeiculo(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(VeiculoAddComponent, {
      width: '500px',
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {});
  }

  listarPaginas() {
    let queryAdicional!: Map<string, string>;
    this.service
      .listPage(
        new PageRequest(
          {
            pageNumber: this.pageEvent ? this.pageEvent.pageIndex : 0,
            pageSize: this.pageEvent ? this.pageEvent.pageSize : 5,
          },
          queryAdicional
        )
      )

      .subscribe(
        (page) => {
          this.page = page;
        },
        (error) => {
          this.page = new Page([], 0);
          this.onError();
        }
      );
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.pages.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.pages.sort = this.sort;
  }

  constructor(
    private service: VeiculoService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listarPaginas();
  }
```

Component.html:

```
<mat-card>
  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="arquivo" (change)="onChange($event)" #upload>
    <label class="custom-file-label">Selecione um arquivo para importação de dados</label>
  </div>
</mat-card>

<mat-card>
  <mat-toolbar style="background-color: #2596be" color="primary" class="toolbar">Veiculos
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="addVeiculo()">
      <span class="material-icons"> add </span>
      Veiculo
    </button>
    <div class="search-veiculo">
      <input matInput placeholder="Pesquisar por Placa" (keyup)="filtroDeDados($event)">
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>


  <div class="mat-elevation-z8 table-hover">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="pages" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="placaOriginal">
        <tr>
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Placa Original</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let veiculo">{{ veiculo.placaOriginal }}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="placaFria">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Placa Fria</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let veiculo">{{ veiculo.placaFria }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="modelo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Modelo</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let veiculo">{{ veiculo.modelo }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="marca">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Marca</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let veiculo">{{ veiculo.marca }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="ano">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Ano</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let veiculo">{{ veiculo.ano }}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row (click)="detalhes(row.id)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    </table>

    <mat-paginator [length]="page.totalElements" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 30, 100]"
      (page)="pageEvent = $event; listarPaginas()">
    </mat-paginator>
  </div>
</mat-card>
```

I did debugging in chrome to test the url in the service, and the url arrives normal (http://localhost:8080/api/veiculos?page=0&size=5)

What i do for fix this bug?

Comment: What table? You have no html anywhere. The bug might be there. Can 'mimic' the URL request with static response locally and reproduce your issue using stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular

Comment: @KaizenProgrammer, I can't use stackblitz, but add html

Comment: Are you declaring and initiating the MatPaginator in the component.ts file ngOnInit() to update the dataSource when you fire the click event?  can you show the full version of your component ts file?

Comment: @Walid Sorry for delay, im declaring declaring the MatPaginator in constructor and initiating in ngAfterViewInit()... I'll post the full code